# Is there a way for permissions to be set through the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

When creating database entries into a Notion database, I'd like to set permissions automatically based on some metric decided by my code logic.

My particular situation is as follows: We have a bunch of issues that are associated with different projects. Some of our members have access to only a few of those projects (a matter of confidential information) and we know who has access to what. As I currently see it, it's impossible to set the permissions with the API, or it is at the very least undocumented. Is there some way to achieve this I am missing? I am not using the SDK, I am calling the API manually, if that helps.

If there is no way to do it, is there a timeline for when it *will* be implemented? This seems like a very basic and important feature for the API to have.

Thanks!

Sidenote: I'm pretty sure it *can* be done by cheating and using the API that the web app itself uses, but this seems like not a great way to go about it.